# GridView: how to hide a template field column dynamic

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, field, hide

I have a gridview with template fields. The last row in the gridview is a totals row which can be positive or string.empty (= null). The idea is as follows: how can I hide a column of the gridview when the totals row = null?
The effect should be that only columns with values are visible. Because the input (that is a year) can be different each time this is a dynamic process.
An example of a template field:

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
       <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="H3" runat="server" ToolTip="Milano-Sanremo" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Milaan-San Remo DESC" Text="MSR" />
       </HeaderTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="R3" runat="server" ToolTip="Milano-Sanremo" Text='<%# Eval("Milaan-San Remo") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

And the way I tried to hide the column in codebehind:

```
        Dim TotalColumns As Integer
    TotalColumns = GridView1.Rows(0).Cells.Count()

    For i As Integer = 0 To TotalColumns - 1
        If i > 4 Then
            For Each row As TableRow In GridView1.Rows
                If row.Cells(2).Text = "Nmbr of Riders" Then
                    Dim lid As String = DirectCast(row.FindControl("R3"), Label).Text
                    If lid = String.Empty Then
                        GridView1.Columns(i).Visible = True
                    Else
                        GridView1.Columns(i).Visible = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

The text "Nmbr of Riders" indicates the totals row. R3 corresponds to the template field above. The code is in the DataBound event of the Gridview.
I tried many other solutions but nothing seems to help. It looks like asp.net does not see any value in the table cells, but perhaps I am wrong.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check GridView datasource. After DataBind(), hide the column.

```
GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
GridView1.DataBind();

// Hide last column
GridView1.Colums[GridView1.Columns.Count - 1].Visible = dataSource.Any(c => c.Nbmr > 0);
```

I don't know your data source structure. Condition can change according to your data source.